# How to create multiple arraylist with dynamic data in java

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I am newbie in Java.please don't put -ve vote. I just want to know.
 I have following data:

```
[john-london-4455-null,mark-newyork-null-null,abishek-null-2244-java developer...may be more]
```

may be more these data dynamic which get from web.

Now I want create in this case, three array list.It is depend upon the data getting from web.

**Edit:**

My intention is, I want to create

```
array1= john, mark, abishek
array2= london, newyork,null
array3=4455,null,2244
array4=null,null, java developer
.
.
.
```

may be more depend upon data.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. If you give more details I'll tell you the perfect solution.

Comment: you wanna put all data in a array .

Comment: Can you please tell in which format you are getting response from server ?

Comment: I am getting data like this- [john-london-4455-null,mark-newyork-null-null,abishek-null-2244-java developer].

Comment: So are you getting `john-london-4455-null` as a single String ? What's  your main problem, 
Extracting value from the String or adding in Array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is some sort of Array of Objects with text separated by hyphens. You can parse this into lists using the following code:

```
String data = "[[john-london-4455-null],[mark-newyork-null-null],[abishek-null-2244-java developer]]";

//first, remove the first and last square brackets
data = data.substring(1, data.length()-1);
//now separate each object by splitting on the commas
String[] parts = data.split(",");

//create the array that will store all your array data
String[][] lists = new String[parts.length][];

//now create each list and store it in your array
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    String str = parts[i].substring(1, parts[i].length()-1);
    lists[i] = str.split("-");
}
```

Now you have the *lists* object to work with. This is more efficient than using `List<String>` too.

Comment: I have above data in arraylist not string. This data in arraylist->>[john-london-4455-null,mark-newyork-null-null,abishek-null-2244-java developer]. So how to split these.

Comment: Thank you Phil, It is very closer of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

create `PersonInfo` Bean class

```
class PersonInfo
{
    String name,loc,add;
    Data(String name,String loc,String add)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.loc=loc;
        this.add=add;
    }
}
```

And create an `ArrayList<PersonInfo>`

```
List<PersonInfo> list = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
list.add(new PersonInfo("john", "london", "4455"));
list.add(new PersonInfo("abishek", "mumbai", "2244"));
list.add(new PersonInfo("mark", "newyork", "3366"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an Utility class like

```
public class PersonInfo{

  String name;
  String loc;
  String add;
}
```

And create an `ArrayList<PersonInfo>`
In this case you don't have to create separate ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code snippet I have written as per my understanding of your problem. I tried to split the `ArrayList` data into array. Then using simple for loops insert the split data into respective lists.

```
  String[] listToArray;
        List<String> one  = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> two  = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("1-name1-addr1");
        l.add("2-name2-addr2");

// l contains the data as you mentioned 

for (Iterator<String> iterator = l.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String string = (String) iterator.next();


    listToArray = string.split("-");

            for(int i =0; i<listToArray.length; i+=3){
                one.add(listToArray[i]);
            }

            for(int i =1; i<listToArray.length; i+=3){
                two.add(listToArray[i]);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(one);
        System.out.println(two);
    }
```

If you needed the output as an array just call `toArray()` method on individual lists.

PS: Things would become more easier if you can opt for beans as suggest by few here.